# IO Completion port Linux equivalent

Tags: linux, multithreading, winapi

Windows OS, A threading model where ThreadPool associated with an IO Completion, ~releasing~ a thread each time an Async IO is completed, the ~released~ thread is then used to deal with the IO completion.

While linux select can be used for async IO it doesn't seem to support the IO Completion / ThreadPool logic.

Is there any Linux equivalent to the IO Completion / ThreadPool above threading model ?

Comment: `select()` isn't quite async. Try libaio.

Comment: True, it blocks until read/write buffers are ready to receive or contain additional data, if not it blocks, and thus, while waiting for multiple descriptors it will stop blocking once any of the descriptors becomes ~available~, having that said, using a single thread for doing select for multiple handles may save the burden~ of other threads doing select ( each for it's own descriptor ) and thus, resulting in an asynchronous behavior those threads ( where a specialized thread is doing select on their behalf )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that does that directly, but you can combine a `select()` loop with a thread pool of your own to get similar behavior.  When `select()` returns and you examine your `fd_set`s to see which file descriptors are ready, push each of those descriptors to a thread pool for processing.  You'll still need a main thread to run the `select()` loop, independent of the thread pool for processing the I/O events.

Most of the complexity in this approach will be in how you keep track of which descriptors need to be included in the `select()` call at each iteration, and in the thread pool itself (since POSIX provides threads but not a standard thread pool API).

You might be interested in using a library like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/), which provides a modular [main loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) that helps with polling on a varying set of file descriptors, as well as a [thread pool](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html) implementation.